# Automatically call Twitter bootstrap-modal.js for <img> tag

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, bootstrap-modal

Fancybox has a feature where it adds the `fancybox` class for each image on a page using something like this `jQuery(thumbnails).addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","fancybox").getTitle();`.

I would like to do something similar with the Twitter Bootstrap Modal for the `<img>` tags so that I don't have to make a call for each and every image. Essentially, I want to use the `bootstrap-modal.js` as an inline image viewer, like a Lightbox/Fancybox.

I found this: http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/ but the demo shows you have to make a call for each and every image.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used  `attr` by attaching `rel=gallery` to images within an `a href` tag:

```
$('a > img').parent().attr('rel', 'gallery');
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Using *[Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)* this is how I managed to get it working without any additional plugin using just Bootstrap's built-in [Modal component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

Add a modal in your HTML page with an `<img>` tag that has an empty `src` like this:

```
<!-- Photo Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="photo-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

               <img src="" />

    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Now let's say you have your thumbnail images inside  links like this:

```
<a class="thumbnail" data-imgpath="pathToImage" data-toggle="modal" href="#">
    <img alt="PhotoName" src="pathToImage">
</a>
```

Use this jQuery code to show the thumbnail image in full size inside the modal:

```
$(function()
{     
    $('a.thumbnail').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var imgPath = $(this).data('imgpath');

        $('#photo-modal img').attr('src', imgPath);

        $("#photo-modal").modal('show');
    });

    $('img').on('click', function()
    {
        $("#photo-modal").modal('hide')
    });
});
```

Add this CSS to center the image inside `<div class="modal-dialog">`:

```
#photo-modal .modal-dialog
{
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

---

Idea taken and adapted from palmerio - [Modal images](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2111#issuecomment-10556056)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to imitate something like rel="lightbox" in bootstrap with the bootstrap modal

first I made my modal window at the bottom of the page

```
<!--- modal for viewing image  --->
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="full-image">
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<img name="pic" src="images/placeholder.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

then in my list of thumbnails I did this in the thumbnail links (my thumbnails names and big image names are output from a query)

```
<!--- change img src using javascript onclick --->
<a title="click to view" href="#full-image" data-toggle="modal" onClick="window.document.pic.src='images/big-image.jpg';"><img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
```

works! :D ~Megan

Answer (score -1):

You could just use an element selector for images.

`jQuery('img').modal();`

A better solution would be to have a parent element or class that identifies which images (presumably thumbnails) you actually want to modalize.

```
<div id="thumbnails">
    <!-- all your images -->
</div>
```

Then use a child selector

`jQuery('#thumbnails img').modal();`

---

*PS. You can use `$` in place of `jQuery` if you aren't trying to avoid library or namespacing collisions.*
`jQuery('img').modal();` = `$('img').modal();`

Comment: I actually tried that before I posted here, and it didn't work. `jQuery('img').modal();` shows a black screen, while `jQuery('#container img').modal();` does nothing.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?  Sounds like your modals aren't being declared properly.